# JaCoCo integration with gwtmockito

Tags: jacoco-maven-plugin, gwtmockito

I am using **JaCoCo** maven plugin for the test coverage reports. It works with MockitoJUnitRunner, but when I use it with tests that run with **GwtMockitoTestRunner** (annotated `@RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)`) I always get zero coverage. In the gwtmockito project documentation there is a JaCoCo support in the version 1.1.5 so I would expect it to work. Can you explain why it doesn't? Is there a way to make it work with JaCoCo, or are there some other tools that can measure code coverage of gwtmockito tests?